# Run jQuery after angular loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to style a table that is rendered with ngRepeat based on JSON that is received using a service that uses `$http.get`.

The problem is that I have side headers and I want to do a border-left like in this picture, but I can't with CSS.

[image]

My code is here: http://embed.plnkr.co/V2E0rLJVVOgOlGLzmrER/preview

So I need to run `jQuery` to style the table with better selectors.

Note that the table is populated in a function inside a controller.

The problem is that I can't do: `.frm-tr:first-child td{border-left: "solid"}`, and inside the controller, after I get the data, I can't manipulate the DOM that is created inside the service `.success` function.

This returns nothing:

> My controller

```
    $scope.dashTable = data.data;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log($('.frm-tr'));
    });
```

> My angular table

```
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding="0" border="1" ng-repeat="table in dashTable" class="frm-quota-table">
<tbody>
    <tr class="frm-table-header" ng-repeat="header in table.Header">
        <th colspan="{{cell.ColSpan}}" ng-if="cell.Index !== 0" ng-repeat="cell in header.Cells" class="frm-headers clearfix" ng-class="{'border-left':cell.ColSpan === 1}">
            <div ng-if="cell.Text !== '' && cell.ColSpan !== 1" class="frm-table-line pull-left"></div>
            <div ng-class="{'pull-left cell-text': cell.Text !== '' && cell.ColSpan !== 1}">{{cell.Text}}</div>
            <div ng-if="cell.Text !== '' && cell.ColSpan !== 1" class="frm-table-line pull-right"></div>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="frm-tr" ng-repeat="content in table.Content">
        <th ng-if="th.RowSpan !== 1" rowspan="{{th.RowSpan}}" colspan="{{th.ColSpan}}" class="frm-side-header" ng-repeat="th in content.LeftPart">
            --&nbsp;{{th.Text}}&nbsp;--
        </th>
        <th ng-if="th.RowSpan === 1" rowspan="{{th.RowSpan}}" colspan="{{th.ColSpan}}" ng-repeat="th in content.LeftPart">
            {{th.Text}}
        </th>
        <td ng-repeat="td in content.ContentPart">
                {{td.Text}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I doubt you need jQuery but if you must it would need to be put in a directive. look into using `ng-class` and other angular core directives first. Suggest reading: [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Please edit the relevant code into this question. You don't need to put it all in your post, but the parts that seem to be the source of the problem should be contained here.

Comment: Put some code in question and efforts you made so far.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to your question; to mark it as 'solved', you accept an answer (which you can't do just yet because you can't accept your own answer for 48 hours).

Answer (score 1):

After discussions with other developers in my team, we did it in angular in a different style:

Solution:

`<td ng-repeat="(ndx, td) in content.ContentPart" ng-class="{'border-left-simple': ndx % 3 === 0}">
    {{td.Text}}
</td>`